# Multiple figures inside a subsection

Tags: floats, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I have an x amount of figures that I want to display inside a subsection. The subsection doesn't contain anything else. Currently the images are automagically put on pages from other sections. What is the correct way to force the images to be put on pages **inside** the subsection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally figures can cross over to other sections, only not to other chapters. The figures are flushed at the end of each chapter with the `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage`) macro. If you don't mind that your next section starts with a new page you can use this macro just before it.

Otherwise, you can use the `flafter` package so that the figures do not move forward from their definition in the text. The `placeins` package gives you `\FloatBarrier` which stops floats to move over it. Place it at the end of your sections after all the figures.

In your case it might be also good to not use `figure` floats, but a non-floating environment (like a simple `center`) together with the `\captionof{figure}` macro from the `caption` package.

See also this [TeX FAQ page](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats) for more information.

Comment: \clearpage works like a charm!